# My server doesn't seem to be caching anything well

Tags: debian, performance, cache

I have a [VPS](http://valkyrie.rustedlogic.net) from tocici (via BuildYourVPS). It's got 4 GB of RAM (2 GB of it "burst" RAM).

This server has some severe performance issues, however. First, a quick explanation of what this server runs:

- Debian 5
- Apache (generally up to date)
- fcgi for PHP
- mysqld
- Some other trivial stuff that it runs

  - memcached, but...

The webserver mainly serves up MediaWiki. Caching is turned entirely off in MW's configuration; enabling memcached is actually *slower* somehow, even though memcached reports decent to great hit rates when enabled (60%, then rises to 90% over time).

The biggest chokehold that seems to be strangling my server's performance is just disk i/o. It's so bad that even a simple `ls` can take forever:

```
xkeeper@localhost:~/logs/wiki.rustedlogic.net$ time ls /root
.  ..  .aptitude  [...]
real    0m0.766s

xkeeper@localhost:~/logs/wiki.rustedlogic.net$ time ls /usr/
.  ..  bin  games  include  lib  local  sbin  share  src  X11R6
real    0m1.460s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s
```

At some times it can get really bad, like this. It's gone further, but...

```
xkeeper@localhost:~$ time ls /etc/log 
ls: cannot access /etc/log: No such file or directory 

real 0m3.887s
```

The iowait can be so awful at times that even *restarting `mysqld`* will actually fail because it times out. (Attempting to `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` again will work, though, usually much faster).

I'm at a loss for what to do next.

Here is a chart from Monit showing the CPU usage at this particular time (the drop at the right being when I restarted Apache and MySQL):
[image: monit cpu usage]

The server isn't exactly choking on RAM, either. Trying to search for a way to increase caching (outside of increasing MySQL's key cache and other things) has proved mostly fruitless; even with outright doubling the cache sizes in MySQL it doesn't seem to have made much of an impact yet.
[image: monit RAM chart output]

If you think it will help, you can also [view the full stats page with rolling charts](http://valkyrie.rustedlogic.net/stats/rustedlogic.net/valkyrie.rustedlogic.net.html).

Running `iostat`:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.00    0.00    0.00   99.18    0.00    0.82
          13.82    0.00    0.88  941878736.18    0.00  142.11
           0.69    0.00    0.69    6.21    0.00   92.41
```

Comment: you get what you pay for.... If this is a VPS how do you know that there are not another 400 customers all trying to use the resources that you are using. Get yourself a dedicated box and you'll see the difference. It will probably cost the same. (on the long run)

Comment: That's the plan in the future, but unfortunately the future is not now. I have to stop the flood before I can replace the pipes!

Comment: Your provider has probably oversold the capacity. Try a different provider and if possible ask him for system statistics.

Comment: I added a bit of `iostat` output to the question at the end. Inodes seem to be at ~12% use as well, so that doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: could you tell me why iowait is showing 99%....

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly out of options with regards to making the VPS perform better since you're sharing the system with many others (sounds like the days of mainframes are returning \o/ ).

I would say get a dedicated server, or at the very least make sure to choose a VPS provider who doesn't over utilize its servers.

Comment: Getting a dedicated server is definitely something in the pipeline, just a bit far off at the moment.